# How to pass an array of string into single variable in php

Tags: php, arrays

Basically, I have a variable called `$userID = $_POST['userID'];` Now currently this can only take one value.

But I want it to take multiple values if possible, so like `$userID = 1,2,4,5` or `$userID = 2` or even `$userID = 1,2,3,4,5,6,7`

I don't know how to do it for multiple numbers but here is my `php` script:

```
<?php
    require "init.php";
function foo()
{
    $numargs = func_num_args();
    echo "Number of arguments: $numargs \n";
    if ($numargs >= 2) {
        echo "Second argument is: " . func_get_arg(1) . "\n";
    }
    $arg_list = func_get_args();
    for ($i = 0; $i < $numargs; $i++) {
        echo "Argument $i is: " . $arg_list[$i] . "\n";
    }
}
    if(!empty($_POST['userID'])){
        $userID = $_POST['userID']; 
        $userID = foo($userID);
        $stmt = "SELECT userID, forename, surname, email, age
                FROM users
                WHERE userID IN (?)";   
        $result = $conn-> prepare($stmt);
        $result->bind_param('i', $userID);
        $result->execute(); 
        $outcome=$result->get_result();
        $response = array();
        if(($outcome->num_rows)>0){
            while($row = $outcome->fetch_assoc()){
                $response[] = array
                (
                    "userID" => $row["userID"],
                    "forename" => $row["forename"],
                    "surname" => $row["surname"],
                    "email" => $row["email"],
                    "age" => $row["age"]
                );
            }
        echo json_encode($response); 
        }
        else{
            echo json_encode("None found");
        }
    }

    ?>
```

EDIT: With the above code I keep getting:
`Number of arguments: 1 
Argument 0 is: 1,2,3
"Failed"` - if `$userID = 1,2,3`

So as you can see `userID` can only take 1 value, but I want to take many in some cases.How do I convert it so that it takes many.

That is the only bit I am stuck on, as the rest of the `SQL` stuff works fine in `phpmyadmin` when I provide it with hardcoded values

Answer (score 0):

You could use [call-user-func-array](http://php.net/manual/en/function.call-user-func-array.php)

Eg:

```
  $userID = "1,2,3,4,5,6,7";
  call-user-func-array(function_name, explode(',', $userID));
```

If you use php 5.6 >, then you can use `...` variadic functions.

[Manual](http://php.net/manual/en/migration56.new-features.php#migration56.new-features.variadics)

As per your comment,

You can use [func_get_arg](http://php.net/manual/en/function.func-get-args.php).

Modified example

```
<?php
function foo()
{
    $numargs = func_num_args();
    echo "Number of arguments: $numargs \n";
    if ($numargs >= 2) {
        echo "Second argument is: " . func_get_arg(1) . "\n";
    }
    $arg_list = func_get_args();
    for ($i = 0; $i < $numargs; $i++) {
        echo "Argument $i is: " . $arg_list[$i] . "\n";
    }
}

foo($userID);
?>
```

Comment: But then `$userID` can be anything, we don't know at compile time only at run time

Comment: @LukazsPioetrszci Check my edit. It will solve your problem

Comment: From the app, it will get the numbers in a list so if it is just `1` then `$userID = 1` if it is `1,3,5` then `$userID = 1,3,5`

Comment: Yes. What is wrong with `func_get_args`? You can pass that variable to the function. Right?

Comment: Also, could you please if you dont mind integrate this into my code?

Comment: Your could do as follows. You just iterate and [concatenate](http://php.net/manual/en/internals2.opcodes.concat.php) all the user id and make an associative array then return the encoded json.

Comment: I get this `Number of arguments: 1 
Argument 0 is: 1,2,3
"Failed"`

Comment: What is your post data?

Comment: `Number of arguments: 1 Argument 0 is: 1,2,3 "Failed"` or `Malformed JSON: Unexpected 'N'` in `POSTMAN`

Comment: I saw that. I am asking about `$_POST['userID']`. What is userID you get? Just `echo` it and check.

Comment: `POST Values: 1,2,3 Number of arguments: 1 Argument 0 is: 1,2,3 "Failed"` - this is what I am getting